# Python Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

Tags: python

tried reinstalling, uninstalling same thing. Windows 10, python 3.9. Any suggestions? Tried now again and it gave me a returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Are you using `pip` or installing the packages yourself?

Comment: I'm using pip. Through Git Bash

Comment: can you add the pip command in the post?
Also adding a screenshot/log of the error will help to debug the issue

Comment: I just did `pip install python-dotenv` on both a windows and linux machine and had no problems, but you could try installing it manually.

Comment: current command that gives me the status 1 error is : pip install dotenv

Comment: If you're using python3 outside of a virtual environment, `pip` may be installing the package for python 2.7. If you have a `pip3`, try with that.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to install the wrong package.

It's `pip install python-dotenv`.

See https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Comment: What version number does it print?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in c:\users\tatiana\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.15.0)

Comment: from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir=path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))

thats my config file. I have a env file in the root directory

Comment: And it still doesn't work when you try importing it now? That might be an issue with your Python setup then (or a developer bug with 3.9), because I tested on two machines (one running 3.8 and the other running 3.7) and it worked fine. Perhaps it's a bug with their version, they said they've added support for Python 3.9 but it might have a bug.

Comment: Is using Python 3.9 essential for your project? If not, I would recommend moving down to 3.8 where most modules are supported right now

Comment: yeah still doesn't work. I'll try installing python 3.8 and come back. Thank you for your time.

Comment: this broke my environemnt. Everything stopped working! pip, python etc, I'll have to spend sometime to rebuild my dev enviorment but I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: took the holiday off. Came back rebuilt everything and now everything works in 3.8. Did I find a bug?

Comment: Glad to know it worked! Possibly, many pip packages are also just slow to support 3.9, so I'd stick with 3.8 for the time being. I'm staying with it for a while at least!

Comment: conda.exe install -p C:/Users/xxx/Miniconda3/envs/pythonProject r-dotenv==1.0.3 -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

Answer (score 2):

Running `python -m pip install python-dotenv` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install python-dotenv.` If still getting the 'ModuleNotFoundError', it could be that python is trying to access it in the wrong directory.

There are ways to go around this which you can find in this video (talks about pandas, but still same jist) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVZQCvRB9v0&list=PLt07sZ5fS9b5WlkbsOCwzKFQyoPthz69X&index=1, but honestly uninstalling and reinstalling python usually fixes things (you'll have to resetup any virtual environments though).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34453767)

Comment: Okay awesome. I'll remember that for next time.